# "Module.exports" autocomplete every time I open a curly brace

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is driving me nuts. Every time I open a curly brace I get an autocomplete suggestion for like 20 lines of code that automatically enters whenever I hit the enter key (which I do after typing a curly brace, obviously).

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMUIZ.jpg

The code that pops up is my tailwind.config.js file verbatim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try switching `accept suggestion on enter` this setting to **off** then suggestion won't be inserted into the editor unless `tab` is pressed or switch to `smart`.

Given that not any plugin is overriding that setting.

If you have doubt why same code is popping up, it might be due to AI based plugin for suggesting (code which you used mostly) or you would have created a code snippet.

Comment: Ah, it was "Pieces" code snippets. Fixed after I re-installed the VSCode extension. Thank you so much.

Comment: Correction: It's a setting inside of the plugin itself that I wasn't aware of. Regardless, thank you.

Comment: Yes, setting can get complex when plugin starts interfering and general setting won't override. Especially when plugin settings has some default value.